# Rails missing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I have the template in my views/layout folder still it is showing missing template.Also twitter bootstrap not working

```
Missing partial layouts/_user_header with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/techbirds/shivam/app/views"
  * "/home/techbirds/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
```

(application.html.erb)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Shivam</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %> alert-dismissable">

        <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="container-narrow">
  <div class="masthead">
    <%= render 'layouts/user_header' %>
    <h3 class="muted"><%= link_to "SimpleDevise", root_path %></h3>
    <h5 class="muted">A demo of using SimpleDB with Devise</h5>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <%= yield %>
</div>

<% if user_signed_in? %>

  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>        

<% else %>

  <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %>  

<% end %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I have added this line //= require twitter/bootstrap in my (application.js)
I have added this line  *= require twitter/bootstrap in my (application.css)

Comment: How are you rendering your partial ?

Comment: yes I have render my partial

Comment: Could you post a quick `ls -R` of your app/views?

Comment: app  bin  config  config.ru  db  Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  lib  log  public  Rakefile  README.rdoc  test  tmp  vendor

./app:
assets  controllers  helpers  mailers  models  views

./app/assets:
images  javascripts  stylesheets

./app/assets/images:

./app/assets/javascripts:
application.js  homes.coffee

./app/assets/stylesheets:
application.css  homes.scss

./app/controllers:
application_controller.rb  concerns  homes_controller.rb

./app/controllers/concerns:

./app/helpers:
application_helper.rb  homes_helper.rb

./app/mailers:

./app/models:
concerns  user.rb

./app/models/concerns:

Comment: ./app/views:
devise  homes  layouts

./app/views/devise:
confirmations  mailer  passwords  registrations  sessions  shared  unlocks

./app/views/devise/confirmations:
new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/mailer:
confirmation_instructions.html.erb  reset_password_instructions.html.erb  unlock_instructions.html.erb

./app/views/devise/passwords:
edit.html.erb  new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/registrations:
edit.html.erb  new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/sessions:
new.html.erb

./app/views/devise/shared:
_links.html.erb

./app/views/devise/unlocks:
new.html.erb

Comment: ./app/views/homes:
index.html.erb

./app/views/layouts:
application.html.erb  _user_header.html.erb 

./bin:
bundle  rails  rake  setup

./config:
application.rb  boot.rb  database.yml  environment.rb  environments  initializers  locales  routes.rb  secrets.yml
./config/environments:
development.rb  production.rb  test.rb

./config/initializers:
assets.rb               cookies_serializer.rb  filter_parameter_logging.rb  mime_types.rb     wrap_parameters.rb
backtrace_silencers.rb  devise.rb              inflections.rb               session_store.rb

./config/locales:
devise.en.yml  en.yml

Comment: ./db:
migrate  schema.rb  seeds.rb

./db/migrate:
20151127051051_devise_create_users.rb

./lib:
assets  tasks

./lib/assets:

./lib/tasks:

./log:
development.log

./public:
404.html  422.html  500.html  favicon.ico  robots.txt

./test:
controllers  fixtures  helpers  integration  mailers  models  test_helper.rb

./test/controllers:
homes_controller_test.rb

./test/fixtures:
users.yml

./test/helpers:
./test/integration:

./test/mailers:

./test/models:
user_test.rb

./tmp:
cache  pids  sessions  sockets

./tmp/cache:
assets

./tmp/cache/assets:
development

Answer (score 1):

please keep the `views/layouts` folder clean. you can put your partials in the folder `views/application`.

if you do it like that, you can do it like this:

```
 `<%= render 'user_header' %>`
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

application.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'layouts/user_header' %>
```

Add the `partial` in `views`

views/layouts/_user_header.html.erb

```
# erb content goes here
```

Comment: This file i already have in my views/layouts folder with name _user_hearder.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

you should review again partial instead bootstrap. Because error message is applyed for partial not bootstrap.